# MySQL query to search for all records against field with comma separated values

Tags: mysql

I have 2 sql tables
Table name: **agents**  contains a records with a coloumn AgentID

Table named: **vacancies** is the one with the data ans is being dislayed.
Table named vacancies has vacancies.Agents which contains values simmilar to this

```
VacanyID    Company       position        CTC        Candidates        Agents
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
FBVAC001  | HDFC      |  Branch Manager | 4.5  | FBCAN001,FBCAN002| Agent3,Agent4
FBVAC003  | TBNH      |  Branch Manager | 4.5  | FBCAN004,FBCAN005| Agent2,Agent4
FBVAC005  | MMNT      |  Branch Manager | 4.5  | FBCAN008,FBCAN006| Agent3
FBVAC008  | LCFC      |  Branch Manager | 4.5  | FBCAN009,FBCAN023| Agent3,Agent4
FBVAC008  | KOTC      |  Branch Manager | 4.5  | FBCAN009,FBCAN023| Agent5,Agent4
```

I want to run a query that will return only those records that contain the value that corresponds to agents.AgentID from table name agents. This is the query so far but all it returs are those records that do not have more than one value in vacancies.Agents

for example if the value being searched for is Agent3 it should return rows1,3 and 4 instead it only returns row 3.

```
SELECT
vacancies.VacancyID,
vacancies.Company,
vacancies.`Position`,
vacancies.CTC,
vacancies.Candidates,
vacancies.Agents
FROM vacancies
, agents
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(vacancies.Agents,agents.AgentID) <> 0)
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have your parameters backwards in `FIND_IN_SET`.  The set should come second

```
FIND_IN_SET(agents.AgentID, vacancies.Agents)
```

More Info: http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=162

---

Also, if you are wanting to see only a specific agent, you need to filter for that as well, otherwise you're getting every possible combination of agent and matching vacancies (hence the duplicate rows):

```
AND Agents.AgentID = 'Agent3'
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4dcb/3

Comment: I reversed it and tried it but it just shows all the rows along with duplicates of each row.

Comment: If you only want `Agent3`, you also need to search for that `and AgentID='Agent3'`.  See my update to the post.

Comment: I mentioned agent3 as a runtime example. I actually want to check it against the column AgentID in the table agents.

Comment: You're getting duplicate rows because some of the vacancies match multiple agents, and some of the agents match multiple vacancies.  What result exactly are you looking for?  Without any filter, the result with duplicates is actually correct.  See for example this update where I include the agentID in the output, and maybe it will make more sense: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4dcb/4

Comment: It's like this. The agent that is logged in is determined in the agents table. Let us say Agent3 is logged in. He should get to view only those records that Have his name(AgentID) in the Agents field of the vacancies table.

Comment: So where does `Agent3` come from?  You need to pass it in as a parameter from somewhere, even if it's dynamic at runtime, and it should filter properly.  So for example you might do something like `FIND_IN_SET('$AgentID', vacancies.Agents)` if it were PHP code and you have a variable `$AgentID` that stores the id of the agent.  Or use a parameter `?` and bind the parameter value before running the query.

Comment: I'm using phprunner to build this. The end result is that The Agent can only see the records that have their name exclusively in the vacancies.Agents field

Comment: So you need to find a way to hook up the value of the current agent id into the query.  I'm not familiar with phprunner, but somehow, you need to pass in the value of the current session agent into the query to filter.  Otherwise how should it know to display only the current agent's records?

Comment: True thats exactly why it has been confusing me. I thought it was a pure mysql query issue

Comment: Where does the agentID come from?  Is it a PHP variable?  Is it stored in a session table in the database?  How do you filter other areas in the site, like My Info for the agent?  You may have to take it up with the phprunner developers or forums to understand how you hook these things together.

Comment: the agentID is stored in the agents table. its data is entered into that table separately. The Agent logs in with his AgentID which is the same one as that in the agents.AgentID field.
Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: Got it to work. In php runner under the Events section I added an sql Where clause `(FIND_IN_SET(agents.AgentID, vacancies.Agents) <> 0) AND agents.AgentID = '".$_SESSION["UserID"]."'";` Thank you @mellamokb

Comment: Right.  That's what I meant by "where does AgentID come from", the agentID of the currently logged in user not the source list.  It comes from `$_SESSION["UserID"]`.  Glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  vacancies.VacancyID,
  vacancies.Company,
  vacancies.`Position`,
  vacancies.CTC,
  vacancies.Candidates,
  vacancies.Agents
FROM vacancies,
  agents
WHERE (select
     agents.agentid,
     vacancies.agentid
   from agents
     left join vacancies
       on vacancies.agentid = agents.agentid)
and agents.agentid = 'Agent3'
```

Comment: agentID doesn not exist in the vacancies table except its values lie in the Agents field of the vacancies table.
Also I cant search directly for Agent3 it has to be taken dynamicaly from agents.AgentID